# how to setting section details in crystal report In order not to repeat itself

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i want display data from crystal report with multiple section details, but i have problem when showing data in details with multiple row from view database. i will share a link picture from preview my report. may be you can understand what i mean. this link picture :

https://pics-edge.slickpic.com/NjU1ODM4NWRmY2Q4NQ,,/20170523/MTM4MTU1NzdmOGNm/p/1400/Slide1.jpg

https://pics-edge.slickpic.com/NjU1ODM4NWRmY2Q4NQ,,/20170523/MTM4MTU1Nzg4Yzg1/p/1400/Slide2.jpg

https://pics-edge.slickpic.com/NjU1ODM4NWRmY2Q4NQ,,/20170523/MTM4MTU1NzlkNThm/p/1400/Slide3.jpg

https://pics-edge.slickpic.com/NjU1ODM4NWRmY2Q4NQ,,/20170523/MTM4MTU1ODA1YzVk/p/1400/Slide4.jpg

https://pics-edge.slickpic.com/NjU1ODM4NWRmY2Q4NQ,,/20170523/MTM4MTU1ODE4Y2Q1/p/1400/Slide5.jpg

https://pics-edge.slickpic.com/NjU1ODM4NWRmY2Q4NQ,,/20170523/MTM4MTU1ODI4ZGNk/p/1400/Slide6.jpg

https://pics-edge.slickpic.com/NjU1ODM4NWRmY2Q4NQ,,/20170523/MTM4MTU1ODNkZGNm/p/1400/Slide7.jpg

and this is an information from my section expert :

```
Report Header
Page Header
Details
 Details a                 Keep Together, Suppress Blank Section => is check
 Details b                 Keep Together, Suppress Blank Section => is check
 Details c                 Keep Together, Suppress Blank Section => is check
 Details d                 Keep Together, Suppress Blank Section => is check
Page Footer
Report Footer
```

thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Try to Check "Suppress if Duplicate"